# Visual Studio 2008 Reporting Services backward compability issue

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services, backwards-compatibility

I know there is an Issue using SQL Server 2000 Reporting Services and Visual Studio 2005, but does this error still exsist with Visual Studio 2008 and 2010?

If so, is there any work-aground to get this working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do know that SSIS 2005 requires VS 2005 and that SSIS 2008 requires VS 2008.  So if you have upgraded your SQL Server 2005 client tool installation to 2008, there is no way (AFAIK) to create SSIS 2005 projects.

My guess is that you will see the same issues with SSRS as with SSIS.

Comment: I see, so that means no compability between newer VS Reporting Services and older SQL Reporting Services ?

Comment: I'm afraid not - although I hope that someone will correct me.